# Why is `x && y` not parsed as `x & (&y)`?

Tags: c, parsing

I'm implementing a C compiler and found a curious issue. Since `&` has higher precedence than `&&`, it seems reasonable to consider it as a binary-and of the first operand with the address of the second:

```
x && y = (x) & ( &(y) )
```

The syntax overview of the C specification seems to allow this interpretation. I'm probably missing or misreading something?

My understanding of the syntax:

> andExpression := equalityExpression | (andExpression '&' equalityExpression) | ...
>   ...
>   unaryExpression := postfixExpression | ( ('&' | '*' | '+' | '-' | '~' | '!') castExpression ) | ...

Comment: Precedence isn't involved.  `&&` is tokenized before the language grammar even comes into play.  Modern compilers first generate a token stream, then apply the language grammar to that token stream.

Comment: Look for the [maximal munch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch) rule.  The longest possible token is identified at each point.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thanks, good hint. I'm indeed not using a tokenizer. Why is the tokenizer allowed to keep the && together instead of splitting it, tho?

Comment: It is more a question of the tokenizer is not allowed to split the double ampersand — because of the maximal munch rule.  The maximal munch rule is why `x = y++++z;` is bogus C, even though if it was spelled `x = y++ + ++z;` it could be valid.  The maximal munch rule means it is tokenized as `x = y ++ ++ + z;` and applying the second `++` to the result of the first is not legitimate in C (though it seems to be legitimate in C++ at least some of the time).

Comment: Aside from the grammatical reason, your proposed interpretation would not mske sense anyway. The operands of & must have arithmetic type and `&y` never can.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

C operator expressions are parsed through something known as "[maximal munch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch)" <sup>1)</sup>, meaning that from left to right, the compiler goes for the longest chunk of symbols that can form a valid token. Since `x &&` is longer than `x &`, the compiler picks the former.

This is why code like `x+++1` compiles, `+++x` does not, but `+ ++x` does.

---

<sup>1)</sup> [C11 §6.4 Lexical elements ¶4](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4p4):

> If the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing tokens up to a given character, the
>   next preprocessing token is the longest sequence of characters that could constitute a
>   preprocessing token.

Comment: Thanks; can you quickly highlight where this behavior is described in the spec? It should be in 6.4 but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @mafu it's indeed in 6.4§4 (emphasis mine): "If the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing tokens up to a given character, the next preprocessing token is **the longest sequence of characters** that could constitute a preprocessing token."

Comment: I added the standard reference to the answer.